# colliding point particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

when I draw e.g. the diagram of compton scattering I assume that the electron of given momentum gets 'hit' by a photon and interacts with it.
How close does the photon have to get to the electron that it is considered a 'hit'. Obviously if passing at a macroscopic distance it shouldn't get affected. And an actual hit should be impossible when dealing with point particles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While electrons are point particles in the sense that their position eigenstates are (as far as we know) $\delta$-like. Photons can't be said to be point particles in this sense, as you cannot transform to their rest-frame (although they are featureless with respect to small scales as far as we know).

The correct way to thing about electrons and photons is as quatum fields, and as such they are extended. So the relevant length scale is not related to the "size" of an electron, but to its scattering cross-section with photons of a given energy. Never forget, a photon is not a point-particle travelling on a trajectory through space. A photon is a quantized portion of an electromagnetical field.

But there is a natural distance scale involved, namely the Compton wavelength. Photons with wavelengths long compared to the Compton wavelength will not Compton scatter on electrons.

Comment: this helps. But given a cross section which I calculate from the feynman diagram, how do I convert this area now into a probability for a 'hit' to happen?

Comment: I found my answer: multiplying the luminosity (which is proportional to the overlap of the, eg Gaussian shaped, beams) with total cross section yields the rate